# How do i resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage' in virtual environment

Tags: python

I am currently running on macOS Big Sur. I am new to this and running on virtual environment. I believed that I had done the necessarily installation. However, jupyter notebook shows "module not founderror. No module named 'skimage' in virtual environment.

```
# packages in environment at /Users/xxxxx/opt/miniconda3/envs/test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi               20.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
async-generator           1.10                     pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     20.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    3.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2021.1.19            hecd8cb5_0
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37hecd8cb5_0
cffi                      1.14.4                   pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
imageio                   2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 5.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   7.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipywidgets                7.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    2.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            6.1.11                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-widgets        1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    10.0.0                        1
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h1de35cc_1
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2
markupsafe                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 6.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_1
nest-asyncio              1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.5                      pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.19.5                   pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1i               h9ed2024_0
packaging                 20.8                     pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    8.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.3.3           py37hecd8cb5_0
prometheus-client         0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.14                   pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.20                     pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.7.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.9                h26836e1_0
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pywavelets                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     21.0.2                   pypi_0    pypi
qtconsole                 5.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
qtpy                      1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.0                  h1de35cc_0
scikit-image              0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                52.0.0           py37hecd8cb5_0
six                       1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.33.0               hffcf06c_0
terminado                 0.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
tifffile                  2021.1.14                pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.10               hb0a8c7a_0
tornado                   6.1                      pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.5                h1de35cc_0
zipp                      3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib          

        1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
```

**Code that I wish to run**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k06G4.png)

**Output**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZA8n.png)

Comment: since scikit-image is installed in this virtual environment, are you certain that you are running your code from the virtual environment? Since you are using jupyter notebooks, create a cell with "!pip freeze" and see if scikit-image is listed there too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the recommend approach from the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html#install-via-pip), I quote:

```
# Update pip
python -m pip install -U pip
# Install scikit-image
python -m pip install -U scikit-image
```

If you use conda:

```
conda install scikit-image
```

To see whether scikit-image is already installed or to check if an install has worked, run the following in a Python shell or Jupyter notebook:

```
import skimage
print(skimage.__version__)
```

Comment: Module still not found. I have applied that into the virtual environment.

Comment: OP seems to have a Conda environment, so this might not be the same thing...

Comment: Try **pip uninstall -U scikit-image** and **pip install -U scikit-image** again.
Your import is correct, your error is just because you either forgot or did not install the package correctly, it works on my notebook

Comment: @AKX, I edited my answer, Isaac, see updated answer, maybe you use the wrong command

Answer (score 0):

Just adding, had the same issue. Used Gaetan's suggestion and it worked fine. I will say, with VSCode, the venv does not add scikit-image via adding to the requirements.txt strategy. You need to head to the command prompt and force your will :) ...once that's done, it's added to the pip list group. Maybe this helps uncover what's the cause of this hiccup. HTH.